# How to print each element of a list of lists in python using the specific elements

Tags: python

I am trying to print a list of lists in python using for loops.  I am having  issues doing so.  Ive tried a couple of approaches.  Here is what I have:

```
for r in range(len(priceChart)-1):
    for c in range(len(priceChart[0])):
        print(priceChart[r][c], end= " ")
    print()
```

I just want each element of the list of lists to be printed out without the brackets or spaces.  Thanks!

Please note:  I need to use for loops!

Thanks so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: Update: Here is code to print out formatted string as weel

Comment: print("%4s" %priceChart[r][c], end= " ")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest to use for-each loops:

```
for l in priceChart:
    for c in l:
        print(c, end= " ")
    print()
```

If you have to use indexes:

```
for r in range(len(priceChart)):  # no '- 1' here, range(x) loops from 0 to x-1
    for c in range(len(priceChart[r])):  # use 'r', not 0
        print(priceChart[r][c], end= " ")
    print()
```

Comment: Perfect that makes sense! Do you also know how to format it so that each time I print and element it uses a default amount of space.(I am printing a list of list with each element having a varying length and I want it to look good)

Comment: @logankilpatrick - [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) is your friend.

Comment: @logankilpatrick Check out the [`rjust`, `ljust`, `center`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust) methods!

Comment: OkI will check it out

Comment: @logankilpatrick i have edited my answer to include your request