# i want to remove sqaure brackets from python list output

Tags: python, pandas, list

```
 df = pd.read_excel('Websites.xlsx', usecols=[3])
 webs = df.dropna()
 weblist = webs.values.tolist()
 for count in range(0,len(weblist)):
     print (weblist[count])
```

the output is

```
['TRIPADVISOR.COM']
['CHASE.COM']
['WEBMD.COM']
['WEATHER.COM']
['INDEED.COM']
['HOMEDEPOT.COM']
['CRAIGSLIST.ORG']
['BANKOFAMERICA.COM']
```

i need to convert this all to website format like https://www.example.com

Comment: You have a list of lists, you need to access the element of the list rather print the list, you should be able to figure this out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print each element of a list of lists in python using the specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875511/how-to-print-each-element-of-a-list-of-lists-in-python-using-the-specific-elemen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think output is one column `Dataframe`, so add [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) for Series, last loop and change `url` with `f-strings`:

```
for i in webs.squeeze():
 print (f'https://www.{i.lower()}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are intending to do, try flattening list of lists:

```
flat_weblist = [i for lst in weblist for i in lst]

 ['TRIPADVISOR.COM',
  'CHASE.COM',
  'WEBMD.COM',
  'WEATHER.COM',
  'INDEED.COM',
  'HOMEDEPOT.COM',
  'CRAIGSLIST.ORG',
  'BANKOFAMERICA.COM']
```

Then joining string:

```
http_list = [''.join(('http://www', i.lower()) for i in flat_weblist]

['http://tripadvisor.com',
 'http://chase.com',
 'http://webmd.com',
 'http://weather.com',
 'http://indeed.com',
 'http://homedepot.com',
 'http://craigslist.org',
 'http://bankofamerica.com']
```